# Getting value from Firebase list response array

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I'm trying to get element values from response to `list()` method when accessing `Firebase` realtime database. I must have some outdated documentation so the answer may be super easy for someone with basic experience in `TypeScript` and `Firebase`.

It starts like this:
I have object `db:  AngularFireDatabase`

I call `db.list('/firebaseElements').snapshotChanges().subscribe(elements=>{let els = elements; ...})`

If I `JSON.stringify(els)` I get `[{"payload":"element1","type":"value","prevKey":null,"key":"1"},{"payload":"element2","type":"value","prevKey":"1","key":"2"},{"payload":"element3","type":"value","prevKey":"2","key":"3"}]`

So if I call `els[0].payload` I should get `element3` string. `element3` is a `leaf` in that database so it is a simple string value. However, if I access `payload` it turns out to be an object with 2 properties `_database` and `_delegate`. My old documentation also references accessing value by `els[i].$value` property but that doesn't seem to be working either.

Hence my question: how do you access simple (leaf) values from nodes retreived from Firebase database?

Answer (score 1):

Well, all I had to do was to `subscribe` to `valueChanges()` and not `snapshotChanges()` and then I get `leaf` values straight away. My bad.